# Django pass request to to_representation method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to override the serializer's `to_representation`. How can I pass the request object in it so I can build url?

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    link = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('name', 'link')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get('request') # Get request here
        return {'foo': request.build_absolute_uri(
                '/apps/foo/{}'.format(
                object.id))
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following method to your viewset to be able to access the request in the serializer:

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    context = {'request': self.request}
    return context
```

If you simply want to add a URL to your serializer, you can add the serializer identity field to your serializer instead of overwriting the to_representation method:

```
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
    view_name='foo-detail',
    lookup_url_kwarg='pk'
)
```

Comment: I got this error: `context={'request': request}`, but when I add it, I also got `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: Are you using viewsets.ModelViewSet in your views? Did you overwrite the def retrieve or def list methods? If so, did you include ```serializer = FooSerializer(instance, context=self.get_serializer_context())```?

Comment: Yes, I use ModelViewset. However I got a different workaround now. Thanks!